# Why does my Perl regex not work to remove certain strings following newlines?

Tags: regex, perl

I have text that looks like this

```
text
\centering
more text
```

I want to convert it to:

```
text
more text
```

Using Perl

#### My code is:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\R+\\centering\R+/\n/g' example.md
```

It doesn't work at all!

Note that both this and my alternative

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\\centering/*/g' example.md
```

produce the
output

```
text
*
more text
```

And

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\R+/\n*/g' example.md
```

produces

```
text
*\centering
*more text
```

So, they work individually, but not together. What am I doing wrong here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `0` as record delimiter, it's more convenient to use `777`

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\R+\\centering\R+/\n/g' example.md
#      ^^^
```

produces the result you want.

From [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode. Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.

Comment: As your citation explains, `-00` will enable "paragraph mode" rather than *"using `0` as the record delimiter"*. Paragraph mode is a perfectly valid option, and it is only because the OP has accepted your answer that I have any reason to imagine that it is not a deliberate choice.